# Can't deploy to secured Service Fabric cluster from VS

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I've created a secured SF cluster from the portal, but I can't connect to the explorer from the browser or deploy my app from VS. I have the cluster certificate (the one it makes you create on a Key Vault when you first deploy the cluster) installed on my machine. I got the .pfx file from the Key Vault and installed it on my Windows machine both with double click/wizard and with Powershell Import-PfxCertificate cmdlet.

Still after that, VS says Failed to contact the server. Please try again later or get help from "How to configure secure connections"

I tried added an client "admin" certificate, but it only asks me for the Thumbprint or the subject name, where I put the ones from the previously created cluster certificate. I don't really know if I need to buy a client certificate to make it work, or where do I get it?

And as I said, I can't access to the explorer using the browser either. Any ideas?

Here some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: certificate subject name doesnt match the dns name you are using

Comment: How do I change that? The certificate I'm using is the one Azure makes you create when you create the cluster for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This error message might be:
- The certificate issuer authority is not trusted
- because the certificate you installed is not valid or does not target the domain you are trying to access.

---

> if the certificate issuer is not trusted, you might have to:

- Trust then, please see [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome)
- Or, get a new certificate from a trusted and execute the steps below

> If the certificate is invalid, or misconfigured:

The message is chrome telling you that the certificate is not valid, and you can proceed on your own risk. You should be okay if you click `Proceed to xyz.dev.eastus.cloudapp.com`.

To deploy applications from Visual Studio to the cluster, you have to install the PFX certificate in the machine, and add the thumbprint to the publish profile file. See more in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-secure-connections)

How to make it work:

- Register the domain you want, here I will say as `www.example.com`
- Register the CNAME record on your DNS provider pointing to your Service Fabric default domain like`xyz.dev.eastus..cloudapp.com`.
- Get a PFX certificate from a trusted authority, or your own self-signed certificate if it is for internal use only.
- Add the certificate to key vault
- Configure the VMSS to use the certificates from key vault
- Update your cluster configuration with your certificate thumbprint

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal) provides the documentation on how to setup the cluster certificates.

And the following link has a detailed explanation how setup applications: 
https://ronaldwildenberg.com/custom-domain-name-and-certificate-for-your-azure-service-fabric-cluster/

If you just want to create secure cluster for Dev and Test purposes, you could just create from the portal and let azure generate the correct certificate for you. For production workloads, you should create your certificates, Please take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal) for more info.

Comment: Diego, thanks for your answer, but I'm still not sure about what I need to do. I don't own any certificate or custom domain (like you said 'example.com'), I just wan't to publish a development cluster on Azure to test my application. I did exactly what the article 'Configure secure connections to a Service Fabric cluster from Visual Studio' says but I still can't make it work.

Comment: For dev and test purposes, you could make use of the auto generated certificates. I've added extra info at the bottom with link to docs.

Comment: Diego, thanks again :) But as I said I'm using the certificate that Service Fabric automatically creates when you create the cluster for the first time. I ve followed the 'Basic Option' (as the doc says: 'To make setting up a secure test cluster easy for you, we have provided the Basic option')

Still don't know what could be wrong, maybe I don't need to download de pfx from the KeyVault and I need to do some other stuff?

Comment: In this case I think the problem is the issuer is not trusted, can you take a look in the first link I've posted in this updated answer

Comment: I already did that, still not working, I really don't know why it could be happening. I could deploy the app using Powershell, using the same certificate, but it doesn't work from Visual Studio

Comment: On visual studio publish profile, check if the certificate store is configured correctly, the thumbprint, and so on. If it works outside VS, should work with the builtin scripts as well. Another issue might be firewall or proxy in your network blocking the connection.